# Error when sorting rows with vertical merge

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets, merge

There must be a way to sort rows even though there is a vertical merge. The current sorting script I am using works perfectly fine **but** ever since I applied some vertical merges to my sheet. It no longer works. I get the following error:

> You can't sort a range containing vertical merges.

Comment: share a copy of your script & sheet

Comment: You should take a look at [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/118955/219752), it might guide you in the right path.